# parallel programming and the <<- assignment operator in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, assignment-operator

i have a question regarding parallel programming and the `<<-` operator in R.
I want to apply the `xfun` function on matrix `x`.
If the entry in the first column is smaller than 0.5, it's supposed to append the entry in the second column to the vector `vec` outside of the function in the global environment.
At the end the function should return the first column plus the random number in `y`.

If i use the regular `apply` function, it works exactly like it should. However i want to apply a similar function to a huge dataset and therefore want to do it in parallel 
via the `future_apply` function from the package "future.apply". But when i do this, the `<<-` operator does not work and `vec` stays empty.
Is there anyone who knows why that is and if there is a way to make it work?

Thanks in advance

```
x <- matrix(runif(20), nrow = 10, ncol = 2)
vec <- NULL

xfun <- function(x) {
  y <- runif(1)
  if (x[1] < 0.5) {
    vec <<- append(vec, x[2])
  }
  return(x[1] + y)
}

# works
xy <- apply(x, 1, xfun)

library(future.apply)
# vec stays empty
xy <- future_apply(x, 1, xfun)
```

Comment: Please do not use **<<-**, read `library("fortunes");
fortune(174)`

Comment: If you want to parallelize tasks, they should be independent. You have the side effect of assigning into one vector. Since a vector is an ordered structure, your tasks are not independent. Furthermore, the standard functions for parallelization do not allow such super-assignment because the workers do not have access to the global environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So i guess i will have to find a different way of doing it.

Comment: One way is to return a list with both the results you want. This has been discussed elsewhere.